# How do I replace remaining occurrences of commas in a string with a pipe "|" delimiter

Tags: c#, regex

I am parsing a file for data import which is comma delimited, but there are commas within quoted strings.  All strings are in double quotes: Example: 123456, "Firstname","LastName","User, Website", 123456,,,, (notice embedded comma in last string) and numbers do not have double quotes.

I have replaced the 3 characters ","  with "|".  (A line or pipe delimiter with double quotes around it.)

Now I need to replace all of the commas (outside quoted strings) with the | (line) delimiter.
I am new to Regex in C#, and tried the following:

```
                string pattern ="\",\"";
                char charpipe;
                charpipe = '|';
                string charpipestring = "\"" + charpipe + "\"";

                Regex commapattern = new Regex("(,)[2,]");
                int i = 0;
                StringBuilder line2save = new StringBuilder();

                //Replace "," with "|" THIS WORKS
                string newline = line.Replace(pattern, charpipestring);
                Console.WriteLine(newline);

                Regex regresult = new Regex(newline);
                
                //Replace commas outside strings with |s THIS DOES NOT WORK
                line2save = line2save.Append(regresult.Replace(newline, commapattern.ToString()));
```

The output from the Console.Writeline(newline) is:
"0014905"|"24"|"10/14/2011"|"22290030C9",,,,

When attempting to replace remaining commas with line delimiter, the output from line2save after my attempt at Regex is:
{(,)[2,]|(,)[2,]|(,)[2,]|(,)[2,]|(,)[2,]|(,)[2,]|(,)

I expect:
"0014905"|"24"|"10/14/2011"|"22290030C9"||||

How do I replace the remaining commas with |s using Regex?

Comment: Additionally, I use the ,,,, as just an example.  There could be any number of commas to replace with | (pipe or line)

Comment: In the first line you say:  _I am parsing a file for data import which is comma delimited_ then use a library that can handle this task and don't waste time to do it yourself.

Comment: Steve - I use BCP (command line and through C#), SSIS, and various other import tools.  Please tell me which of these or what tool will ignore embedded commas in strings when a comma is the delimiter?  This is inherited code that I am trying to fix from a previous developer.

Comment: https://www.filehelpers.net/ and a question similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974657/filehelpers-quote-and-comma-in-fields